# Loading other angular apps within a shell angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extjs

I am looking for way to load **other angular applications within a shell angular application**.
The scenario is like different teams would build different angular apps, which should be loaded within a shell app the end user's would see. Much like a portal application allowing the user to switch between the apps using the shell.

I am open to idea's and am looking for ways how this can be achieved in angular based applications. All the apps including the shell app would reside on the same host.

Since coming from the Flex dev background, the closest example I can share is one swf loading the other swf.

Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will have to use iframes to load the different shell applications.

Comment: @ganaraj, agreed, that is my last option. If it cannot be done through angular for now.

Comment: Is this problem solved ? Can you provide a outline of the solution.

Comment: @Rohit we went ahead with a different approach given the time constraint and dropped the shell idea.

Answer (score 0):

In place of creating different angular application, I prefer creating different module for each application and inject them as a dependency in main module, you can show different view/controller using route.

hope this will help

Comment: The problem with creating different modules is that, currently angular expects to load them all at bootstrap. Deferred loading is a hack that can be implemented as well. Trying it out, but the module's would be loaded by different urls like: http://abc.net/module1 & http://abc.net/module2.